# How to repair (and is it worth the trouble to) a rusty dishwasher rack?

Tags: rust-removal, rust-proofing

I've seen a couple of solutions:

- Dishwasher paint, like Uber Goop
- Silicon
- Vinyl paint

But some reviews of some of the "paint" products say it doesn't last long.
If this is only a temporary repair it might be best just to get another rack for $100 or so (rather than spending $10 and an hour to just have to repeat it in a month.

Also someone recommended running lemonade (unsweetened mix packets) through the dishwasher to initially remove the rust.

Answer (score 3):

ReRack from Performix (same people that make Plasti-Dip) is specially made for repairing dishwasher racks. [It has decent reviews on Amazon.com.](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B000WUBJZS)

Answer (score 0):

be sure to remove as much rust as you can and coat with a rust conversion coating first. Home depot sells some like must for rust that work well to reduce rust comming back.