# "Plastifying" rusty integrated dish drying rack (food contact)

Tags: kitchens, rust-proofing

I have a **dish drying rack** integrated inside a slot above my sink. It is now **rusty** but I haven't been able to find a new one with the right size, despite searching in many stores.

Since the rusting seems to be only superficial, I have been thinking I might remove the rust then "plastify" it somehow so that it does not start rusting again immediately.

I have found spray products like "Plasti Dip" and "Rust-oleum" but they seem to be for cars and floors, so I am not sure about how safe they are for contact with wet plates and glasses. A person [used such a spray on a dish rack](http://craftygemini.com/2012/06/dish-rack-remix.html) but then used the dish rack to store non-alimentary things.

I can't use the solution at [How to repair (and is it worth the trouble to) a rusty dishwasher rack?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/14518/how-to-repair-and-is-it-worth-the-trouble-to-a-rusty-dishwasher-rack) since my rack is totally rusty, I can't just "repair" it with the suggested product that bonds to the remaining vinyl.

How can I avoid rust while ensuring food safety?

[image: drying rack above sink]

Comment: If the rack can be removed I would powder coat it. There are home powder coat kits that can be cured in an oven. I built a smoker that I powder coated the racks back in 2000/2001 and they have held up really well even after being scrubbed and soaked to remove the food residue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are completely safe for use.  But before you apply one of these plastic products,  first get some rust reducer.  Sand or scrape to remove most of the rust, and then apply the rust reducer.  These reverse the oxidation process as well as providing a smooth surface suitable for painting or covering with those plastic products.